# bootstrap 3 customized fixed navigation on scroll with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in the navigation bar and stick to top while scrolling to bottom of the page. Its fade effect works only the first time. My code is below.

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .navOpacity{
        opacity: 0;
     }    
   </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

     $(window).scroll(function(){

       var ht = $('header').height()+70;

       if($(this).scrollTop() >= ht){
          $("#navb").addClass("navbar-fixed-top navOpacity")
           .fadeTo('slow','1');
          $(".row:first").css("padding-top","50px");
       }else{
          $("#navb").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top navOpacity");
          $(".row:first").css("padding-top","0px");
       }

     });

    });

  </script>

   <div class="container">

        <header class="page-header"> 
         <h1>Hello world</h1>
         </header>

        <nav id="navb" class="navbar navbar-default">

         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
             data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                     
            </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
         </div>

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                   <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
         <h3>h1. Bootstrap heading</h3>
         Hello world and Mario.
        </div>

       <div class="col-md-4">
         <h3>h2. Bootstrap heading</h3>
         Hello world and Mario.
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-4">
         <h3>h3. Bootstrap heading</h3>
         Hello world and Mario.
         <img src="rsz_myimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
       </div>

    </div><!-- end or row class-->
 </div><!-- end container class-->
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: I hope it's fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that after the first time `fadeTo` is executed, your element is left with a `style="opacity: 1"` attribute, which is left there. So you have to remove it when you scroll to the top.

I've also changed the way the navbar is hidden, I suggest using `.hide()`, cause it also uses the elements' `style` attribute, that way it will not be overridden. And there's also a `navbarVisible` var that is used to determine if the navbar is already faded in and if it is, the code for fading it in is not executed when not needed. This should be a tiny step up in performance.

This seems to work just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var navbarVisible = false;

        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var ht = $('header').height()+70;

            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= ht) {

                if (!navbarVisible) {
                    $("#navb").addClass("navbar-fixed-top")
                        .hide()
                        .fadeTo('slow','1');

                    $(".row:first").css("padding-top","50px");
                    navbarVisible = true;
                };
            } else {
                $("#navb").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top").removeAttr('style');
                $(".row:first").css("padding-top","0px");
                navbarVisible = false;
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

You **don't** need this part anymore:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .navOpacity{
        opacity: 0;
     }    
</style>
```

Here's a link to an example JSFiddle with working code: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/p0vaz7zv/)

Comment: @MariosNikolaou, sorry, there was a bug. I've updated the code in my answer and also added a working JSFiddle, please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

Just add this Javascript and away you go. Currently configured to graduate over the first 200px of scroll.

```
var scrollFadePixels = 200;

var fadeNavbar = function (window)
{
    var opacity = window.scrollTop() / scrollFadePixels;
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,' + opacity + ')');
}

fadeNavbar($(window));

$(window).scroll(function () {
    fadeNavbar($(this));
});
```